# Multiple routing with same paths but with different complex parameters

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

For example:

`api/file/occurrence?sha256=...`

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/file/")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFileBySha256Async([FromUri] FilesBySha256RequestDTO requestDTO)
{
}
```

`api/file/occurrence?sha256=...&from_date=..&to_date=..`

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/file/")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFileBySha256AndDateAsync([FromUri] FilesBySha256AndDateRequestDTO requestDTO)
{
}
```

And the DTOs:

```
public class FilesBySha256RequestDTO
{             
    public string sha256 { get; set; }
}


public class FilesBySha256AndDateRequestDTO
{
    public string sha256 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? from_date { get; set; }
    public DateTime? to_date { get; set; }
}
```

How can I accomplish this behavior? I am getting the following exception:

`"ExceptionMessage": "Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nGetFileBySha256Async on type Cynet.Client.WebAPI.Controllers.FileController\r\nGetFileOccurrencesSha256 on type Cynet.Client.WebAPI.Controllers.FileController`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to distinguish the route between two because `api/file/occurrence?sha256=...&from_date=..&to_date=..` and `api/file/occurrence?sha256=...` is the same thing for the framework. The first thing you can do is changing the second route like `api/fileOnDate/`. If it is impossible to do it, you can define a third function and use it as a manual router such as;

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/file/")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFileBy([FromUri] FilesBySha256AndDateRequestDTO requestDTO)
{
    if (!requestDTO.from_date.HasValue && !requestDTO.to_date.HasValue)
    {
        return await this.GetFileBySha256Async(new FilesBySha256RequestDTO() { sha256 = requestDTO.sha256 });
    }
    else
    {
        return await this.GetFileBySha256AndDateAsync(requestDTO);
    }
}

private async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFileBySha256Async(FilesBySha256RequestDTO requestDTO)
{            
}

private async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFileBySha256AndDateAsync(FilesBySha256AndDateRequestDTO requestDTO)
{
}
```

hope it helps.